# Combined conditionals in pypugjs

Tags: javascript, python, pug, jinja2

I'm using pypugjs (https://github.com/matannoam/pypugjs) to render templates on a flask webserver.
The documentation on conditionals in the original Pug module (https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html) is limited, but does say that essentially it is simply javascript.

I have no problem with simple conditionals. Things like:

```
if elem == 'something'
```

works nicely.

However, I can't get combined conditionals to work. When trying something like this –

```
if elem == 'something' || elem == 'else'
```

I get an error like: **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '|'**.

I have also tried variants with parantheses enclosing both or individual expressions, OR-operator instead of ||, omitting second reference to variable after operator, but the error appears similar.

Does anyone know if it is the case that pypugjs cannot compile combined conditional expressions to valid jinja template language? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Jinja2` is a Python based module, so it won't recognize `||` as an `or` operator. You just have to change `||` to `or`.

So, instead of:

```
if elem == 'something' || elem == 'else'
```

Try:

```
if elem == 'something' or elem == 'else'
```

Comment: There you go. Thanks.